# Problems with xindy and glossaries

Tags: indexing, glossaries, mactex, xindy

I'm having a bit of a problem creating a glossary.
I'm working with a MacBook using Mountain Lion OS 10.8.3, I've installed [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/) 2012 and details about [`xindy`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xindy) are:

```
xindy release: 2.4
xindy script version: 1.16
xindy kernel version: 3.0
CLISP version 2.48 (2009-07-28) (built on richard-kochs-computer.local [10.0.1.2])
architecture: X86_64
```

When I try to run this programme

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen, xkeyval, xfor, amsgen}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{translator}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{real number}
{
    name={real number},
    description={include both rational numbers and irrational numbers},
    symbol={\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
}

\newglossaryentry{Agypten}
{
name = {{Ä}gypten}
description = {German:Egypt}
}

\chapter{Model chapter for a report}

This is the first chapter of the report. Most certainly it will have
    some \glspl{real number}. Maybe there will be
    something in German, like \gls{Agypten}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Now when I run [`makeindex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) in the terminal like this:

```
pdflatex document
makeindex document.glo -s document.ist -t document.glg -o document.gls
pdflatex document
```

it would work if I hadn't used Umlauts. Considering my Bachelor's thesis will most certainly be in German that would be rather suboptimal. Upon finding out that `xindy` works multilinguallx, I tried that as well:

```
pdflatex test
xindy -L german -I xindy -M test -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
pdflatex test
```

For which I receive:

```
Cannot locate xindy module for language german.
```

Well considering I can locate that module I thought I might tell her where it is, but unfortunately I couldn't find out how. The other way would be copying that module in a directory `xindy` is using to find the modules but I couldn't figure that out either.

Of course I also tried the simple version:

```
makeglossaries test
```

Where the output was:

```
No \@istfilename found in 'test.aux'.
Did your LaTeX run fail?
Did your LaTeX run produce any output?
Did you remember to use \makeglossaries?
```

Funny thing is: A couple of lines above that statement I saw this:

```
\@istfilename{test.xdy}
```

But when I looked into `test.aux`, it wasn't there. When I put it there and ran the command again there was simply no compiler output, which was probably because of `xindy` I guess.

I hope someone of you can help me with that.

Comment: Sounds like it's [this problem](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=3) in which case the solution is either to upgrade to the latest version of `glossaries` or use the workaround in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I've tried updating glossaries but somehow after that I get error messages and can't find the package anymore... I get this message for a start:

    ! LaTeX Error: File `datatool-base.sty' not found.

And then it continues on like that... I'll try the other way.

Comment: You also need to update `datatool`.

Comment: I'm afraid none of them work, I ran all the updates on tlmgr, even the one on tlmgr itself but still can't seem to get it to work. It still says that it can't find the module for german. I tried the workaround as well but nothing happens there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set document language to german to let `glossaries` know how it should sort entries. Due to `xindy` bug, you also have to set encoding manually:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen, xkeyval, xfor, amsgen}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}
\usepackage{translator}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{real number}
{
    name={real number},
    description={include both rational numbers and irrational numbers},
    symbol={\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
}

\newglossaryentry{Agypten}
{
    name = {{Ä}gypten},
    description = {German:Egypt}
}

\chapter{Model chapter for a report}

This is the first chapter of the report. Most certainly it will have
    some \glspl{real number}. Maybe there will be
    something in German, like \gls{Agypten}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Important lines are `\usepackage[german]{babel}` and `\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}`.
Note that you missed comma in `Agypten` glossary entry.

Edit:
if `makeglossaries` still don't work, try this:

```
xindy -M lang/german/duden-utf8 -I xindy -M test -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

Comment: That's right I forgot to post that, I had it on ngerman! I changed it to german and added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} as well but it still won't work.

Comment: @DavidWright I edited my answer. it is still doesn't work, please add log from xindy run to your question

Comment: You Sir are my hero. Thank you so much I've been working on that forever, your last line made it work!

Comment: Inspired from the answer below, there is a one-liner way without changing babel package:
\usepackage[xindy={language=german,codepage=duden-utf8}]{glossaries}

Answer (score 0):

Something similiar happend to me (Arch Linux, custom TeX Live install) using `LuaLaTeX` and `makeglossaries`. @michal.h21 provides [an apparent solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111215/46734): execute `xindy` manually, passing the name of the language/encoding module found in **modules dir** (cf. `man xindy`). I do not need to set `\GlsSetXdyCodePage` in the TeX document.

MWE (in my case, I'm writing in Spanish):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Charis SIL}% This font not essential to the example, just what I use
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries

\newacronym[shortplural={PPNNSS},longplural={polimorfismos de nucleótido simple}]
    {PNS}{PNS}{polimorfismo de nucleótido simple}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\dots el \gls{PNS} rs2710102 \dots

\end{document}
```

Processing:

```
a=resumen-6; lualatex $a; xindy -M lang/spanish/modern-utf8 -I xindy -M $a -t $a.glg -o $a.gls $a.glo; lualatex $a
```

**Edit**:

I've discovered how to get `makeglossaries` to work in my case: by passing the correct values to the `xindy` option of the `\usepackage{glossaries}` call, e.g.:

```
\usepackage[xindy={language=spanish-modern,codepage=utf8}]{glossaries}
```